# Discrete Abelian subgroups of Euclidean isometries

Tags: lie-groups, isometry, integer-lattices

Suppose $\Gamma$ is a discrete, cocompact Abelian subgroup of the Lie group $\mathrm{E}(n) = \mathbb R^n \rtimes \mathrm{O}(n)$ of Euclidean isometries, where $$(b,A)(b',A') = (b+Ab', AA') \quad \forall \: (b,A), (b',A') \in \mathrm{E}(n)$$
I would like to prove:

> If $\Gamma$ acts freely on $\mathbb R^n$, then $\Gamma$ is a lattice in $\mathbb R^n$. In particular, for every $(b,A) \in \Gamma$, we have $A = \mathrm{Id}_n$.

Because $\Gamma$ acts freely on $\mathbb R^n$, if $(b,A) \in \Gamma$, then the equation $b + Ax = x$ has no solution; in particular, $b$ is not in the image of $\mathrm{Id}_n - A$. So $A$ must have an eigenvalue of $1$. But this is about as far as I've been able to get. Any thoughts?

**EDIT:** As was pointed out to me, cocompactness is a necessary assumption. I found a good exposition of this result in Louis Auslander's AMS article "An Account of the Theory of Crystallographic Groups".

Comment: $\Gamma$ acts as a discrete group of translations. Therefore the linear part is the identity matrix.

Comment: $\Gamma$ acts freely is not enough, e.g. screw translation in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @user10354138 Is this an abelian discrete (cocompact) subgroup of $E(3)$? This is the assumption, I thought.

Comment: It isn't cocompact, but you can certainly get abelian discrete out of, e.g., the subgroup generated by $(b,A)$ where $A=\begin{pmatrix}&1\\-1\\&&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $b=e_3$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Showing that $\Gamma$ acts as a discrete group of translations is precisely what I'm trying to prove. Does this follow from the hypotheses I've laid out (after including cocompactness)?

Comment: Yes, it is from the theory of crystallographic groups (so cocompact is required).

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, every abelian crystallographic group is a lattice of translations. Do I have this right? And if I do, do you happen to have a source I can look up the proof in?

Comment: Most likely, this is proven in Wolf's book "Spaces of constant curvature".

Answer (score 1):

**Not an answer**

(Or, more accurately, an answer to the question before you changed it...)

Skipping the co-compactness that you added later, pick $b = \pmatrix{0\\0\\1},  A = \pmatrix{0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1}$ and you've got the screw translation mentioned in the comments. The slab $\Bbb R^2 \times [0, 1]$ is a fundamental domain. $A$ does in fact have $1$ as an eigenvalue, but that's not enough to get you the "translation" conclusion that you want.

In short: co-compactness appears to be essential. *